# Windows 11 Browser videos are not visible behind transparent CMD window

Tags: windows, terminal, windows-11, intel-graphics

Hi I am experiencing a strange issue with my recently installed Windows 11, I adjusted transparency of CMD terminal window such that the background contents are visible. It helps to read documentation while typing different commands, so the Issue is when I play a YouTube video and start a terminal with Fullscreen the video is not shown instead a backscreen. But I can hear the audio when I click on browser to activate the window and CMD losses focus the video can be seen normally. A screenshot is attached for better understanding of issue.

[image]

**NOTE: It works perfectly fine in Windows 10**

Comment: Have you checked that your browser is actually outputting video, and not only audio? May be your browser that it detects that the app does not have focus and thus not rendering video as a powersaving feature. To rule out: try with a different browser, preferably non chrome, eg firefox. You can also put the terminal window open outside, and then move it over partially so you should see either the video playing through or also black outside.

Comment: @LPChip just tested with Firefox, the only difference is Edge shows backscreen while out of focus, but Firefox locks the latest frame at the point of going out of focus. Audio keeps playing no video. Works with partial window. But not with maximized window of terminal

Comment: So it is a focus feature then. Don't know if you can disable it, but I would just not maximise the window, and instead drag its corners to fill the screen. That should work.

Comment: @LPChip its a one workaround as a my last option, can you suggest some thing proper from Microsoft settings or configurations or changes in regestery

Comment: I don't like Windows 11 enough that it is not my daily driving windows. I know it has a feature to remove distractions. Something with focus. I bet that is currently active. Maybe accessible from the bottom right, near clock, or settings or something.

Comment: This is a resource saving feature and is disabled differently per browser. Chrome based browsers have a "pause background tabs" or "calculate native win occlusion" option in chrome://flags and more options that can cause videos to pause playback. Other websites use javascript to stop playback as soon as tab focus is lost. Other issues might be at play, like hardware rendering beying enabled/disabled. I suggest looking into the relevant focus flags first.

Comment: @Silbee but why this behavior is totally different in windows 10? And assuming if this is so then how can I disable this I am using Edge and Firefox

Comment: edge://flags for edge and about:config for firefox. There are so many variables here. Does it only happen with youtube or every other video streaming site as well ? As for there being different behaviouor between windows 10 and 11, that could mean a number of things, jjust another variable to complicate things. Might be a windows feature, might be a browser feature specificly for windows 11, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated your problem and did as suggested in the comments already. In edge, you can browse to `edge://flags` and set `"Calculate window occlusion on Windows"` to `Disabled`.

After doing that, chrome rendered Youtube (and other video content) fine with a fullscreen Terminal overlay.